# Searching vertices with minimal “variance”

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

> Suppose $\Gamma(V, E)$ is a strongly connected oriented graph and $|V| = n$. Let’s define *distance* from vertex $v_1$ to vertex $v_2$ as the minimal possible length $d(v_1, v_2)$ of an oriented path from $v_1$ to $v_2$. Let’s define *variance* of a vertex $v$ as $\sum_{u \in V} (d(v, u))^2$. What is the computational complexity of finding a vertex with minimal variance? The graph is given by its adjacency matrix.

On one hand, it is clearly $\Omega(n^2)$ because it takes that time to process the input. On the other hand, there exists an algorithm that works for $O(n^3)$:

Firstly, we use DFS to determine the distances from any vertex to any vertex. DFS is $O(n^2)$ and will be initiated $n$ times. Thus $O(n^3)$.  Then we calculate the variances of each vertex using the distances. That’s $O(n^2)$. And then we choose the vertex with the minimal one. Thats $O(n)$. $O(n^3) + O(n^2) + O(n) = O(n^3)$.

But maybe some better algorithm exists...

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths. Given the output of APSP (i.e. all the distances $d(u, v)$), the remaining step to compute variances takes $O(n^2)$ time, so fast algorithms for APSP are helpful here. As seen on that page, APSP can be solved in time $O(mn + n^2 \log \log n)$ (where $m = |E|$). This is good for sparse graphs (with small $m$), but for graphs with large $m$, other algorithms are preferable: the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0008011.pdf gives an $O(n^{2.575})$ time algorithm (not sure if this is the best known).